# How to change number of ticks in x-axis in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, scatter-plot, x-axis

I have below scatter plot

[image]

There should be 6 years [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022].
There are two problems:

1. The string of years is not complete.
2. There are 5 ticks instead of 6.

Here is some part of my code:

```
  const xAxisG = g.append('g')
   .attr('transform', "translate(0," + innerH + ")");

  const yAxisG = g.append('g');
  const xValue = d => d.year;
  const xScale = d3.scaleTime();
  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);
  xScale
    .domain(d3.extent(data, xValue))
    .range([0, innerW]); 
  
  const circles = g
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr("transform", "translate(92,0)")
  
  circles
    .attr('cx', d=>xScale(xValue(d))) // Use the scales to conver the original values
    .attr('cy', d=>yScale(yValue(d)))//? yScale(yValue(d))+40 :null)
    .attr('r', 5)
    .attr('fill', d => {if (d.classification_for_rate_setting == "B") return "steelblue"; return "orange"})
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)")
    .append('title')
    .text((d) => `${d.primary_reason}\n${d.new_percent_change}\n${d.classification_for_rate_setting}\n${d.effective_date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'short',year:'numeric'})}`);

  xAxisG.call(xAxis)
    .selectAll('text')
      .attr("transform", "translate(40,10)")
  yAxisG.call(yAxis)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is stored differently, so first:

```
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat((d) => '2' + Math.round(d*1000)); // change to 2XXX
```

There's the correct number number of ticks. The first tick is directly under the y-axis. Don't adjust your tick labels.

```
xAxisG.call(xAxis)
//.selectAll('text')
//.attr("transform", "translate(40,10)")
```

EDIT:

Remove the circle translate as well

```
  const circles = g
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    //.attr("transform", "translate(92,0)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I used your answer like this and it worked:
 `const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat((d) => Math.round(d)); `. But as I translated all the circles to x=40 so I need to translate the x-Axis too. so how can I do that?